# Variable is not passing from helper.js to apexcontroller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
navigateUrl : function (component, event, helper) {
var action=component.get('c.DeletingRecord');
action.setCallback(this,function(response) 
                   {
                       var state=response.getState();
                       var rid = component.get("v.Provider.Id");
                       action.setParams({abc : rid});
                       alert(state);
                       console.log('rid'+rid);

                   });
$A.enqueueAction(action);

@AuraEnabled
public static void DeletingRecord(string abc){


    system.debug('Key'+abc);
    list<SysConct_Provider_detail__c>   SPDList = [select id,name from SysConct_Provider_detail__c where Id = : abc ];
    system.debug('SPDList'+SPDList);
    delete SPDList ;
    system.debug('SPDList2'+SPDList);
```

Comment: @glls Why did gave negative marking can i know ?

Comment: I did not downvote you, however, i would assume that the lack of details or effort to resolve might have contributed to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the parameters for an action in the callback function. The callback doesn't execute until after the server call is complete.

You need to move these lines:

```
var rid = component.get("v.Provider.Id");
action.setParams({abc : rid});
```

outside the callback and prior to

```
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your params before calling the callback method.

What your doing is setting params inside the callback due to which after callback your params are getting set and which may result in null or undefined value.

> Below code should work:

```
action.setParams({abc : rid});
action.setCallback(this,function(response) 
                   {
                       var state=response.getState();
                       var rid = component.get("v.Provider.Id");
                      // action.setParams({abc : rid});
                       alert(state);
                       console.log('rid'+rid);

                   });
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```